# Using Google Transit information in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, gtfs

Google transit provides approximate time of the next bus arriving at a particular bus-stop when you click on the bus-stop icon. This works for trains and even metro lines.
Is there *any* way I can use these transit information in my own map view? I tried going to the link that is displayed under the timings ( I guess it means thats where google is getting the timings from) but that link is broken...doesnt exist...it must be providing the information to Google only...
So is there any way i can access the Google Transit information?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i had to drop the idea...its only available for usa at the link given by @Robby but is (currently) unavailable for quite many countries.
Hoping itll be available soon.
Thx for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data feeds are publicly available and published by the corresponding transit agencies. The available list is [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds). You'd need to download the data and host it or include it in your app.

Comment: just for USA? :| where can i get for other countries?

Answer (score 1):

In the "worst case scenario", you could download the result of a web query to maps.google.com (such as `http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=new+york&daddr=boston&dirflg=r`) to your app and parse the result. Maybe there are even sample-scripts that already do this!

Comment: umm..im not sure how will i do this..but ill try searching for some info on this...arent there any data feeds available for timings etc?...the previous comment found them for usa but nt for any other country..